# How to get user addresses from mapping?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, remix, dapps

I am  having trouble trying to get addresses from a mapping.

```
code 1 :mapping (uint8 => address payable[])  playersByNumber; // list of players with their number
code 2 : uint8[] public numbers; // all numbers being stored in this array

    function enterNumber(uint8 number) public {
   
     playersByNumber[number].push(payable(msg.sender)); // pushes number to the mapping w/address
        numbers.push(number); // pushes number to number array.
    }

function getPlayers() public  view returns (address[] memory  ){
 `what code should be here?. `

}
```

Just returning the address would not work.

Regards

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do?  Return address from just one `numbers` or return all the addresses from all the `numbers`?

Comment: Hi @shubhamskatel I'm creating a lottery app which I need to return all addresses from the numbers (this means they've entered the current lottery)

Answer (score 0):

````
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;



contract ReturnAddressesFromMapping{
    mapping (uint8 => address payable[])  playersByNumber; // list of players with their number
    uint8[] public numbers; // all numbers being stored in this array

    function enterNumber(uint8 number) public {
   
     playersByNumber[number].push(payable(msg.sender)); // pushes addresses to the mapping
        numbers.push(number); // pushes number to number array.
    }

//typcasting the "returns address" returns addresses from the mapping 
function getPlayers(uint8 number) public  view returns(address payable[] memory){
     return playersByNumber[number];


}

}```
````